# Google maps directions on webpage

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have managed to get a map of my location on my webpage, but I want to be able to add to option for a customer to type in their location & the route is then mapped on the map on my webpage.
I have searched around & there are demo's online, but they all take you off to a new window or the Google maps page. I want to contain the directions on a map that is already shown on my page.

from a comment:

```
<script> 
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(x,x); 
function initialize() { 
 var mapProp = { center:myCenter, zoom:10, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }; 
 var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp); 
 var marker=new google.maps.Marker({ position:myCenter, }); 
 marker.setMap(map); 
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content:"x" }); 
 infowindow.open(map,marker); 
} 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
</script>
```

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  If your map is based on the Google Maps Javascript API v3, it supports [directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: Please, please, please don't post code in the comments (it can't be formatted to be readable).  Edit your question to address comments by including any requested code in your question.  In any case, that is Google Maps Javascript API v3 code, what issues are you having with using the directions service?

Comment: [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4c.html) translated to v3 from [This example: More advanced stuff - Part 26: Get directions on your own map](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/directions.htm) in [Mike Williams' Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/)

Comment: These examples seem to have fixed 'To' & 'From' locations. I won't have a fixed 'From' location, only a fixed 'To' position where I would be guiding people to...

Comment: Thanks, I think you may have solved it for me! I will have a play. Sorry, I just couldn't get my head around it & needed a few pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mjrulesamrat/qagkso5c/3/
You can find the Github repo here: https://github.com/mjrulesamrat/google_maps

As can be seen in the demo there is a search bar where you can type in your location.

```
<input class="controls form-control pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

In your case you could fix the end location. Map reloads based on input, so no other windows are opened.

Check it out and customize it as you want! Hope this helps...

Comment: I don't think this is quite what i'm looking for.
I would like a map on the page with a search bar next to it where the user can type in their postcode/address. Then when they click the Search button, the route is then mapped onto the map next to the search button.